# Crystal "or IF" function error

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi I need help with a crystal or IF formula I cannot seem to get to work, here is how I think the formula should be written:

```
If {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No}= [0000,9452] and 
   {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} <> ["1-Accepted","Unknown"] 
then 0 
else {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP} 
or if {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No}= [9281] and 
      {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} = ["13-Itinerary Changed,6-Cancelled"] 
then 10 
else {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP}
```

The formula before the OR IF part works fine but cannot get the other bit after this to function, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is no OR IF. You can say OR and add the second condition, but then, because you need another else you might need to use a elseif or an inner if.

I have no way to test this, but try adding some indent formatting and the code as follows:

```
If {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No} = [0000,9452] and {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} <> ["1-Accepted","Unknown"] then 
            0 
    else 
        if {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP} 
            or ( {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No}= [9281] and {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} = ["13-Itinerary Changed,6-Cancelled"] ) then 
            10 
        else 
            {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Like Carlos, I think the problem is at least partly caused by the use of `or if` after `else`, although I think there are a couple of other problems too. Try this:

```
If {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No} in [0000,9452] and 
   {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} not in ["1-Accepted","Unknown"] 
then 0 
else if {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No}= 9281 and 
        {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} in ["13-Itinerary Changed","6-Cancelled"] 
then 10 
else {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses:

```
If {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No} = [0000,9452] and {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} <> ["1-Accepted","Unknown"] Then 
            0 
    Else (

        If {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP} OR ( {'GPD_Data_'.Deal No}= [9281] AND  {'GPD_Data_'.Saving Accepted ?} = ["13-Itinerary Changed,6-Cancelled"] ) Then 
            10 
        Else 
            {'GPD_Data_'.% Charges in GBP}
)
```